# For a convex function, does having a unique minimizer imply that it is coercive?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

I am looking for a simple proof that if a functional is convex and it has a unique minimizer, then it must be coercive. To be specific, let ${\cal H}$ is a Hilbert space and $G$ is a functional on it. If $G$ has a unique minimizer on ${\cal H}$, i.e. $\exists f_0 \in {\cal H}$ such that $G(f_0) < G(f), \quad \forall f \in {\cal H}, f \neq f_0$. How can we prove that $G(f) \rightarrow \infty$ when $\|f\| \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 5):

It is not true: take $\ell_2$, and let $e_n$ be a Hilbert basis. Then
$$G(f)=\sum_n \frac1n \langle f,e_n \rangle^2$$
is convex, its unique minimum is zero, but for instance $G$ is bounded along the sequence $\sqrt n e_n$, which goes to infinity in norm.

EDIT: if the dimension is finite, it is true. Call $N$ the dimension. Suppose without loss of generality that $G(0)=0$ is the minimum. Since $G$  is convex, then it is continuous. Therefore its minimum $m$ on $\mathbb S^{N-1}$ is strictly positive, by compactness and the strict inequality for the minimum. Then by convexity, along every half line through the origin the growth of $G$ is at least linear with slope $m$, i.e. $ G(f)\geq m \|f\|$, from which the result follows.

Comment: Thank you so much for this example. If the dimension is finite, can we prove $G$ is coercive? Could you please help me to get a simple proof?

Comment: @drbombe In that case it's true. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Here is what I tried. Please comment to see if there is a simpler proof. Let $\|f_n\| \rightarrow \infty$. If $\cal H$ has finite dimension, we can find a basis $e_i$ such that the projection of $f_n$ on $e_i$ goes to infinity, i.e. $\exists a_n \rightarrow \infty$, and $f_n = a_n e_i + f^1_n$. Suppose the minimizer is $f_0 = e_i + f_0^1$. We have $$G(f_0) < G(f_0 + 1/a_n(f_n^1-f_0^1)) \le (1-1/a_n)G(f_0^1) + 1/a_n G(f_n)$$. By taking $a_n$ goes to infinity, we have $G(f_n)$ goes to infinity. Any simplier or more direct proof? Many thanks again for your help.

Comment: I don't understand your conclusion. Anyway I'll edit the answer to add this case

Comment: Thank you so much for providing your comment. Could you please provide a little detail on how compactness and finite dimension play roles here? It seems that we can use the same argument for general Hilbert space, e.g. If $G(0)=0$  is the minimum, $\forall f \in {\cal H}, f \neq 0$, $0 < a=G(\frac{f}{\|f\|})=G(\frac{f}{\|f\|}+ (1-\frac{1}{\|f\|}) \cdot 0) \le \frac{1}{\|f\|} G(f)$. Then we have $G(f) \ge a \|f\|$. It seems that we need to use information for finite dimension.

Comment: The fundamental fact we used here is that the sphere of a normed space is compact if and only if the dimension is finite. This ensures that the continuous function $G$ has a minimum, which must be strictly positive by the assumption on the strict minimum. In infinite dimension the infimum may be zero without being attained, which is the case for the example in the answer. Finite dimension also implies that a convex real-valued function is continuous. In conclusion: in infinite dimension, even if you required the continuity of $G$, the $a$ of the previous comment could be zero.

Comment: Thank you so much! My reputation got 15 today and I immediately vote your answer up :) I still got some confused. If $0$ is the unique minimizer. $f \neq 0$, We must have $G(f/\|f\|)>0$, right? So $a$ should be great than $0$ for any fixed $f$. Then $G(f) \ge a\|f\|$ is true for any $f \neq 0$. Did I miss something?

Comment: Maybe I got you confused, in my previous comment I really wanted to say: the *infimum* of the possible values of $G(f/\|f\|)$ could be zero (without being zero for any $f$, otherwise there would not be uniqueness of the minimum point)

Comment: I see you are really an expert in analysis. If possible, I do have another question on my statistics research. It will be great that you can help me to a right direction. Your help is highly appreciated!! http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1992133/if-coercive-in-a-subspace-implies-coercive-in-a-bigger-space-under-these-conditi

Comment: **Expert** is a bold word. Anyway glad to help you! I'll have a look