# Convex function with unique critical point is coercive

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis, coercive

> Let $V:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R} \in \mathcal{C}^1$ such that $V$ is
>   convex and $V$ has a unique critical point.
>
> Then $V$ is coercive.

This was an example given in one my lectures. But it sounds like one of this examples for which there might a counterexample due to non-formal statement...

Can you prove that is right? Or there is such a counter-example?

**References**

The similar questions window tells me that in fact [For a convex function, does having a unique minimizer imply that it is coercive?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1989525/for-a-convex-function-does-having-a-unique-minimizer-imply-that-it-is-coercive) is not true in general Hilbert space. What about finite-dimensional ones?

Comment: Your reference already contains a proof for the finite-dimensional situation...

Comment: @gerw let me read It with more attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that statement is correct but the proof is not so easy. See Corollary 8.7.1 in Rockafellar's *Convex Analysis*.