# condition for convex function to have unique minimum value

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

The question is related to

[Convex function with unique critical point is coercive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2731599/convex-function-with-unique-critical-point-is-coercive)

Assume we have a function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ and we know that $f$ is just convex, not strictly nor necessarily strongly context. Also, $f$ is coercive.

Support is finite dimensional, but could be unbounded.

Is this enough condition for the function to have a unique minimum value?

Comment: You should be able to argue via compactness of a suitable leven set (by coercivity) and continuity in the interior of the domain (by convexity and finite-dimensionality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gather "coercive"—which is a term I was not previously acquainted with—simply means [$\ \lim_\limits{\|x\|\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=\infty\ $](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coercive_function#(Extended_valued)_coercive_functions). The function $\ f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\ $given by
$$
f(x)\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\cases{0&if $\ \|x\|\le1$\\
\|x\|^2-1&if $\ \|x\|\ge1$}
$$
would then suggest to me that the answer to your question is "no".